# Are there any similar progress bars with interactions like this?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, progress-bar

I'm actually looking at circular progress bars that can fit in the 45px x 45px space, as such there's a limit to what can be displayed (so the typical long and narrow progress bar isn't going to work well there).

I was wondering if there are examples of similar behaviours that have been implemented for displaying progress to the user like the one described below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question? Are you asking for examples where this functionality has been used before?

Comment: Can you describe the behavior?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for examples where this function has been used before. Right now I can only think of after effects, and then use after effects file to integrate.